# Words with by "er-" and "ver-" as prefixes

Tags: standard-german

What are some words that take both "er-" and "ver-" as prefixes? Are there qualities to these words that allow them to be prefixed by both?

Comment: suchen, langen, ziehen, bringen. I do not think that asking for a list of words is a good fit for this site.

Comment: @CarstenS Maybe as a CommunityWiki?

Comment: Most unprefixed verbs can go both with *er-* and *ver-* and the resulting verbs tend to follow no systematic difference in meaning.

Answer (score 4):

I used a [word list](https://sourceforge.net/projects/germandict/) and then went over the results by hand. Some of these words are less frequent than others, so use with care.

> achten
>   arbeiten
>   bauen
>   bieten
>   bitten
>   blassen
>   bleichen
>   blühen
>   borgen
>   brechen
>   bringen
>   denken
>   dichten
>   drücken
>   erben
>   fahren
>   fassen
>   fechten
>   folgen
>   frieren
>   füllen
>   geben
>   gehen
>   glimmen
>   glühen
>   graben
>   grauen
>   greifen
>   halten
>   handeln
>   hängen
>   härten
>   heben
>   heiraten
>   hören
>   jagen
>   kaufen
>   kennen
>   klären
>   klingen
>   künsteln
>   langen
>   lassen
>   laufen
>   leben
>   legen
>   leiden
>   lernen
>   lesen
>   löschen
>   messen
>   mitteln
>   pressen
>   raten
>   rechnen
>   richten
>   saufen
>   schaffen
>   schießen
>   schlagen
>   schließen
>   schrecken
>   schwimmen
>   sehen
>   setzen
>   spielen
>   spüren
>   stehen
>   steigen
>   stellen
>   sterben
>   strahlen
>   streben
>   suchen
>   teilen
>   tragen
>   träumen
>   trinken
>   wachsen
>   wählen
>   wehren
>   weisen
>   wirken
>   wirtschaften
>   wischen
>   wünschen
>   ziehen
>   zählen

Comment: I cannot believe that I was bored enough to do this.

Comment: It's fun to read though, now that you've compiled it.

Comment: @EndreBoth for me to, I often need a moment to recognise the words.